# Custom Error Page in PlayFramework2.4.x

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I did these and still can't see my custom page, please help,

1. Added `MyGlobal.java extends GlobalSettings`
2. Added `onHandlerNotFound` to override:

   `@Override
   public F.Promise<Result> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
       Logger.error("onHandlerNotFound!");
       return Promise.<Result> pure(Results.internalServerError(views.html.page404.render()));
   }`
3. Added `application.global = "MyGlobal"  in application.conf`

But nothing happends, **play2.4.6** still runs out the default page from `devNotFound.scala.html` in **playframework** source folder of `framework/play/src/main/scala/views/defaultpages/`

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it in Play 2.4.x is to use an `HttpErrorHandler` as documented here:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaErrorHandling

You can just extends the `DefaultHttpErrorHandler` and add return your custom pages:

1. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaErrorHandling#Extending-the-default-error-handler
2. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/http/DefaultHttpErrorHandler.html

Here is a full example, considering that you are trying to override the default 404 page:

```
package com.acme.controllers.handlers;

import play.*;
import play.api.OptionalSourceMapper;
import play.api.UsefulException;
import play.api.routing.Router;
import play.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler;
import play.libs.F.*;
import play.mvc.Http.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import javax.inject.*;

public class ErrorHandler extends DefaultHttpErrorHandler {

    @Inject
    public ErrorHandler(Configuration configuration, Environment environment,
                        OptionalSourceMapper sourceMapper, Provider<Router> routes) {
        super(configuration, environment, sourceMapper, routes);
    }

    @Override
    protected Promise<Result> onNotFound(RequestHeader request, java.lang.String message) {
      Logger.error("onHandlerNotFound!");
      return Promise.pure(Results.internalServerError(views.html.page404.render()));
    }
}
```

And then, you need to configure in your `conf/application.conf` like this:

```
play.http.errorHandler = "com.acme.controllers.handlers.ErrorHandler"
```

Comment: So you are just pointing us to the docs?  How about an example? ( No docs are not enough ... The don't call a view or a specific page )

Comment: @PiNg2Eiw sorry, for this case, I thought that docs would be enough. Anyway, I've added a full example.

Comment: @marcospereira thanks for your help, i just posted the screenshot, it really works.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public Promise<SimpleResult> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
        return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(internalServerError(views.html.page404.render()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your code? Answers with no explanation are not as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
    @Override
protected F.Promise<Result> onNotFound(RequestHeader request, String message) {
    Logger.debug("onNotFound: " + message);
    return Promise.<Result> pure(Results
            .ok(views.html.admin.page404.render(request.method(), request.uri())));
}
```

Thanks for help, it really does work in dev env..

I already had the MyErrorHandler.java but not overriding the onNotFound function, because i was almost lost in the extending GlobalSettings's onHandlerNotFound.

Comment: Yea how about accepting his answer? If you feel like someone helped you out, then accept his/her answer. This is how SO works.

Comment: @PiNg2Eiw yeah, i just clicked :). Also thank you for helping how to accept my first question on stackoverflow.